# Why instance variables get initialized before constructor called?

Tags: java, constructor

I have this following piece of code:

```
public abstract class UCMService{
    private String service;     

    protected DataMap dataMap = new DataMap(); 

    protected class DataMap extends HashMap<String,String> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4014308857539190977L;

        public DataMap(){
            System.out.println("11111");
            put("IdcService",service);
        }
    }

    public UCMService(String service){
        System.out.println("2222");
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Now in console the `System.out.println` of `DataMap` constructor is executing before the constructor of `UCMService`.

I was wondering why it is happening.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is because at compile time, the compiler moves every initialization you have done at the place of declaration to every constructor of your class. So the constructor of `UCMService` class is effectively compiled to:

```
public UCMService(String service){
    super();  // First compiler adds a super() to chain to super class constructor
    dataMap = new DataMap();   // Compiler moves the initialization here (right after `super()`)
    System.out.println("2222");
    this.service = service;
}
```

So, clearly `DataMap()` constructor is executed before the `print` statement of `UCMService` class. Similarly, if you have any more constructor in your `UCMService` class, the initialization will be moved to all of them.

---

Let's see the byte code of a simple class:

```
class Demo {
    private String str = "rohit";

    Demo() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

compile this class, and execute the command - `javap -c Demo`. You will see the following byte code of constructor:

```
Demo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1   // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: ldc           #2   // String rohit
       7: putfield      #3   // Field str:Ljava/lang/String;
      10: getstatic     #4   // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      13: ldc           #5   // String Hello
      15: invokevirtual #6   // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      18: return
```

You can see the `putfield` instruction at line 7, initializes field `str` to `"rohit"`, which is before the `print` statement (instruction at line `15`)

Comment: Really wonderful explanation. BTW, I haven't try it, but I may want to use some tools to look at compiler generated codes every time I encountered initialization order problem.

Answer (score 13):

**Short answer**:
Because the spec says so.

**Long answer**:
It would be very strange for the constructor to be unable to use inline-initialized fields.

You want to be able to write

```
SomeService myService = new SomeService();
public MyConstructor() {
    someService.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Wait, so some people told me not to do work in the constructor. I took this to mean, only assign variables in the constructor. Does someService.doSomething() count as work?

Comment: If doSomething() actually does something, then yes - that's work.

Comment: @nos and if `doSomething()` doesn't do something, then it should be renamed to something more descriptive.

Comment: @InspiredOne: A constructor should do whatever is necessary to produce a valid object instance.  While it is sometimes reasonable to have objects start in a mode where the only thing one can do with them is call an initialization method, it is often [not always] more helpful to design a type so that there are no "not-yet-useful" modes.  That having been said, using field initializers to create things that require cleanup is dangerous because there's no way to clean them up if a constructor fails.