# Assigning final keyword using a method

Tags: java, final

I was just playing with final keyword and observed the below behavior, here i am assigning a final variable using a method and the method is getting called before the constructor

```
 public class Test {

    final int i=init(1);

    Test(){
        System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
    }

    public int init(int i){
        System.out.println("Inside Method");
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Test i=new Test();
        System.out.println(i.i);

    }
```

The Output of the following code is as below

```
Inside Method
Inside Constructor
1
```

I know final variable needs to be assigned before the constructors completes and this is what is happening here

What i am unable to find is that how can a method be called before a constructor, i really appreciate any explanation for this

Comment: Probably dup of [Can I call methods in constructor in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230565/can-i-call-methods-in-constructor-in-java) as you are initializing your instance member during construction. Call to the constructor is only part of the construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `final`keyword. Try below(just removed `final` ) output will be same. Basically instance  variable will be initialized first then constructor is called

```
public class Test {
     int i = init(1);

    Test() {
        System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
    }

    public int init(int i) {
        System.out.println("Inside Method");
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start");
        Test i = new Test();
        System.out.println(i.i);
    }
}
```

**Now why and how instance variable get initialized before constructor**  see [Why instance variables get initialized before constructor called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830103/why-instance-variables-get-initialized-before-constructor-called)

Comment: yes i know that this will work without final,my bad i dint put in the question and from the given link i got that the compiler moves every initialization  to every constructor but here since it is a method does this mean that method is called before construction ends , so far what i know is a object must me used for using a method

Comment: Yes, a method can be called before construction ends. Yes, this can result in screwy behavior if you're not careful.

Comment: i found out that a instance method can be called from constructor only after call to super constructor  completes

Answer (score 2):

If you change your constructor to

```
Test(){
    super();
    System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
}
```

and set a debug point to `super();` you will see that the constructor gets called before the `init(1);`. It just gets called before your `System.out.println("Inside Constructor");`.

You can also write:

```
public class Test {
    final int i;

    Test(){
        super();
        i = init(1);
        System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
    }

    public int init(int i){
        System.out.println("Inside Method");
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Test i=new Test();
        System.out.println(i.i);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour in the code is correct and has nothing to do with your analysis about the final key word...

`init(1);` is a method that is getting called as soon the class is constructing an instance...

there fore all inside the method will be executed even before the constructor...

Comment: init(1) will not be called as soon as class is loaded but when object is getting created